# Orchard CMS Custom Forms Validation positioning

Tags: css, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am using the [Orchard Custom Forms module](https://orchardcustomforms.codeplex.com/), and as you can see my problem here:
 [image]

Is that the validation message is down and to the right of where I want it (on the email form).  What is the css handle I can use to re-position those correctly, or how can I stop that from happening? I can't seem to nab it with firebug.

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong. How do you want things to appear? Advice on repositioning depends entirely on your code. Can you post an example? EDIT: O, right, the popup is one box too low. Still, until we know what code is being used to make it that way, there's no way to suggest what to change.

Comment: It is the Orchard Custom Forms - I will put a link - I thought the title was enough, sorry

Comment: Hm, I just want a link to an example of the form. That link doesn't really tell me where I can see an example. Even downloading the code wasn't much use! I'm sure you could make this easier. :-)

Comment: What theme are you using?